# Why is 45 degree line off?

Tags: actionscript-3, math, geometry, angle

I am drawing 2 lines:

1. x:10, y:10; angle: 45 deg; length: 100
2. x:25, y:10; angle: 45 deg; length: 100

Here is the image from the two lines:
[image]

The upper left is, of course (0,0).
The line on the left appears to be drawn correctly. What is happening on the sencond line?

Here is my formula for converting the degrees and length to end points:

```
    var radians:Number = angle * Math.PI / 180;

    _x2 = Math.cos(radians) * length;
    _y2 = Math.sin(radians) * length;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Both** lines are wrong, the formulas for both endpoints should be:

```
_x2 = x + Math.cos(radians) * length;
_y2 = y + Math.sin(radians) * length;
```

Comment: D'oh ... I don't know why I missed that. Hopefully this ends up being helpful for someone else.